# Flexslider not working properly - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider, wordpress-theming, flexslider

I'm trying to setup FlexSlider on WordPress following a youtube, but not sure why the slider isn't working. The console shows no error! All the images are loaded but on top of each other.

**functions.php**

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  add_image_size('slides', 960, 400, true); // slides Flexslider

function html5blank_header_scripts()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

          wp_register_script('conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
        wp_enqueue_script('conditionizr'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js', array(), '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'), '2.7.1', true ); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('flexslider'); // FlexSlider

        wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!


    }
}
// Load HTML5 Blank styles
function html5blank_styles()
{

    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/flexslider/flexslider.css', array(), '2.7.1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('flexslider'); // Enqueue it!
}
```

**header.php**

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

        <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <script>
        // conditionizr.com
        // configure environment tests
        conditionizr.config({
            assets: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>',
            tests: {}
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myslider',
        'orderby' =>'menu_order',
        'post_per_page' => -1
    );
    $slides = new WP_Query($args);

    if($slides->have_posts()):?>

    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <?php   while ($slides->have_posts()): $slides->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('slides'); ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>

            <!-- header -->
            <header class="header clear" role="banner">

                <div class="navcanvas">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                            <!-- nav -->
                            <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
                                <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
                            </nav>
                            <!-- /nav -->
                    </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
            </div><!-- /.navcanvas -->


</header>                   
        <!-- wrapper -->
        <div class="wrapper">
```

**Scripts.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    'use strict';

//alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation:"slide"
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**Console Output**

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
```

Comment: `ignore the line below` - don't even read it, it's a brain virus?

Comment: had to add that! otherwise stackoverflow won't let me post, too much code. haha

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, i fixed it by enqueuing the Jquery file in the header not in the footer

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.4.js', array(), $theme_version, false );
```